# Python список,разделение элемента

Tags: python, массивы

В общем проблема такова,есть список с числами нужно сделать так,что бы при поступление такого же нового списка каждый элемент этого списка писался без цифры 0 в начале.Помогите пожалуйста,нужно срочно.

```
[0775993438',
 0769020467',
 0762555454',
 0768838495',
 0777293171',
 0762567904',
 0768478734',
 0771488311',
 0688623553',
 0761806097',
 0761497756',
 0770258948',
 0772632588',
 0774247799',
 0771591391']
```

Comment: список с числами или со строками?

Comment: Список со строками

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
old_s = ['0775993438', '0769020467', '0762555454', '0768838495', '0777293171', '0762567904', '0768478734', '0771488311', '0688623553', '0761806097', '0761497756', '0770258948', '0772632588', '0774247799', '0771591391']

new_s = [i[1:] for i in old_s] #новый список без нулей

print(new_s)
```